# Query for Gridview sqldatasource

Tags: sql, sql-server

in my asp.net+vb+sql web. i have a query and the schema at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fcdb/8

I'm currently using:

```
with T1 as (
SELECT KNO, Pl, case when KDPR in (4,5) then 'Jr Supdt' 
                     when KDPR >= 6 then 'Others' else '?' end as rank,
       Status
  from STAFF
)
SELECT Pl, rank, Held= (Present+AL+CL), Present, AL, CL
  from T1 pivot (Count(KNO) for Status in (Present, AL, CL)) as P
  order by Pl desc, rank desc;
```

Which produces:

```
|   PL |     RANK | HELD | PRESENT | AL | CL |
|------|----------|------|---------|----|----|
|   SN |   Others |    1 |       0 |  0 |  1 |
|   SN | Jr Supdt |    2 |       1 |  1 |  0 |
|   SH |   Others |    1 |       0 |  0 |  1 |
|   SH | Jr Supdt |    1 |       0 |  1 |  0 |
| Offr |        ? |    3 |       2 |  1 |  0 |
|   HS |   Others |    1 |       0 |  1 |  0 |
|   HS | Jr Supdt |    1 |       1 |  0 |  0 |
```

I want two different queries.

1. The same query out put as i had mentioned in my schema without Offr Engr (Offr Engr should not come in result out put) but sequence should be Jr Engr then Othres.
2. Out put with Offr Engr (Sequence of output Offr Engr then Jr Supdt and then Others.i use a code for the different grade people in a company.

KDPR 1-3 are Offr Engrs, KDPR 4-5 are Jr Supdt, KDPR 6 and above are Others.

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
with T1 as (
SELECT KNO, Pl, case 
    when KDPR in (1,2,3) then 'Offr Engr' 
    when KDPR in (4,5) then 'Jr Supdt' 
    when KDPR >= 6 then 'Others' else '?' end as rank,
    Status
from STAFF
)
SELECT Pl, rank, Held= (Present+AL+CL), Present, AL, CL
    from T1 pivot (Count(KNO) for Status in (Present, AL, CL)) as P
    WHERE rank <> 'Offr Engr'
    order by Pl desc, rank desc;
```

The answer above is for question 1: as I understand, you want to filter out 'Offr Engr' from your query.

```
with T1 as (
SELECT KNO, Pl, case 
                     when KDPR in (1,2,3) then 'Offr Engr' 
                     when KDPR in (4,5) then 'Jr Supdt' 
                     when KDPR >= 6 then 'Others' else '?' end as rank,
       Status
  from STAFF
)
SELECT Pl, rank, Held= (Present+AL+CL), Present, AL, CL
  from T1 pivot (Count(KNO) for Status in (Present, AL, CL)) as P
  order by
    CASE rank WHEN 'Offr Engr' THEN 1
      WHEN 'Jr Supdt' THEN 2
      WHEN 'Others' THEN 3 END;
```

The answer above is for question 2: as I understand, you want custom ordering on `rank` column.